# pypdf text extraction throws IndexError on some PDFs

Tags: python, pypdf, text-extraction

I'm using Python (v 3.10.11) and pypdf (v 3.17.0) to extract the text from several PDFs.

Recently I ran into a particular kind of file from which I cannot extract text because the library throws an exception.

> ```bash
>     File "...\pypdf\_cmap.py", line 481, in type1_alternative
>         if words[3] != b"put":
> IndexError: list index out of range
> ```

<sup>full code ahead</sup>

The files are not encrypted and I'm able to get their metadata (according to it, the files are created using TCPDF) and perform other operations but the issue arises whenever I try to use the `extract_text` function on one of its pages.

A sample of non-text-extractable PDFs can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/frzq6dgumah3ryaq4hyal/example.pdf?rlkey=zwifl5919w870oejhoroptvws&dl=0).

I have searched for people/topics facing the exact same issue/exception but I haven't found them. However,I think I might be facing a situation like the ones described in [Python text extraction does not work on some pdfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272269/python-text-extraction-does-not-work-on-some-pdfs) or [PyPDF2 Font Read Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74388460/pypdf2-font-read-issue)

Looking for other options I have found that Pypdf2 (which as far as I know it´s already deprecated and maintainers/developers have moved their efforts to pypdf) can extract the text.

Code sample:

```python
# from pypdf import PdfReader
# from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")
number_of_pages = len(reader.pages)
page = reader.pages[0]
text = page.extract_text()
print(text)
```

If I run it using PyPDF2, I will get the proper text:

> ```
> CÁMARA DE COMERCIO...
> ...
> ...
> ```

If I try to use pypdf I'll get:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "...\prueba_pdf\test.py", line 8, in <module>
>         text = page.extract_text()
>     File "...\prueba_pdf\venv\lib\site-packages\pypdf\_page.py", line 2284, in extract_text
>         return self._extract_text(
>     File "...\prueba_pdf\venv\lib\site-packages\pypdf\_page.py", line 1903, in _extract_text
>         cmaps[f] = build_char_map(f, space_width, obj)
>     File "...\prueba_pdf\venv\lib\site-packages\pypdf\_cmap.py", line 29, in build_char_map
>         font_subtype, font_halfspace, font_encoding, font_map = build_char_map_from_dict(
>     File "...\prueba_pdf\venv\lib\site-packages\pypdf\_cmap.py", line 54, in build_char_map_from_dict
>         map_dict, space_code, int_entry = parse_to_unicode(ft, space_code)
>     File "...\prueba_pdf\venv\lib\site-packages\pypdf\_cmap.py", line 224, in parse_to_unicode
>         return type1_alternative(ft, map_dict, space_code, int_entry)
>     File "...\prueba_pdf\venv\lib\site-packages\pypdf\_cmap.py", line 481, in type1_alternative
>         if words[3] != b"put":
> IndexError: list index out of range
> ```

Is there a way to make pypdf work in this scenario? Am I missing something?

P.S. I would prefer to keep using pypdf instead of having more dependencies in my project.

Comment: It looks as if either pypdf has a bug or the PDF is broken in a way that we cannot deal with so far. Please submit a bug report: https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/issues - if possible, add the PDF that causes the issue. Please use the bug template. We will try to fix it in the next release :-)

Comment: You should absolutely keep using pypdf! PyPDF2 is deprecated and the text extraction is worse (although we added the big noticable improvements to PyPDF2 before we switched to pypdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted a bug report as suggested by [@Martin Thoma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/562769/martin-thoma).

Indeed, it was a bug that was fixed with the release of version  [3.17.2](https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/releases/tag/3.17.2), so now text extraction works on this kind of pdf files.